# delete fine uploader file icon from Gallery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fine-uploader

I am using REACT to develop my UI and I am using FineUploaderTraditional to upload files. My page where I do uploads has a Gallery component, and when I drag files into the Gallery, they get uploaded immediately. This all works fine. However, I have a separate list of files that were uploaded, and I have a Javascript function that calls an AJAX endpoint that deletes the uploaded file on the server side. This AJAX endpoint returns "success" when it completes successfully. However, when I delete the file this way, the file icon is still shown in Gallery.

What I want to do is fire some function in Javascript/React that tells Gallery to remove that file from display, ie to stop showing it in the Gallery. How can I do that? Does Gallery have any sort of attached function that makes this possible?